# Algolia's autocomplete.js custom markup for the search field?

Tags: vuejs3, algolia, autocomplete.js

I'm trying to use Algolia's autocomplete.js library (NOT instantsearch) with some custom sources, within a Vue 3 app.

All things are working fine, but I discovered that I encounter a couple of issues that I'm not able to manage:

- I'm not able to set input props (like readonly/disabled)
- I'm not able to unwrap the whole component from the `form` tag.

Any suggestions on what steps should I take next?

I know I could create a custom renderer as described [here](https://www.algolia.com/doc/ui-libraries/autocomplete/guides/creating-a-renderer/) but I think it's counterintuitive to rebuilt the whole damn component just to set some basic props?

Minimum example: https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-einstein-t469pl?file=/app.tsx

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not possible without rewriting the whole component.

Further more, the official guide will cover you only if you're using React. If, like me, are on Vue, you need some extra work to make it work. See:

https://github.com/algolia/autocomplete/issues/870